# Roughness penalty matrix for the Fourier basis functions

Tags: r, regularization, smoothing, functional-data-analysis

I am trying to understand how the roughness penalty matrix for the Fourier basis functions is calculated in `R` using the `fda` package.

The roughness penalty matrix for the Fourier basis functions is defined as (see pages 62-63 of [Ramsay, Hooker, and Graves (2009)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387981840))
$$
\mathbf R = \int L\phi(s)L\phi'(s)ds
$$

where $L$ is the harmonic acceleration operator given by $Lx=\omega^2Dx+D^3x$ with the derivative operator $D$ and $\phi$ is the $K$-vector of Fourier basis functions given by $\phi_0(t)=1$, $\phi_{2r-1}(t)=\sqrt 2\sin(r\omega t)$ and $\phi_{2r}(t)=\sqrt 2\cos(r\omega t)$ for $t\in(0,1)$ with the parameter $\omega$ determining the period $2\pi/\omega$.

Consider the case when $\omega=2\pi$ and $K=5$ (when $K=3$, $\mathbf R=0$). We can calculate the roughness penalty matrix in `R` using the `fda` package and the following code.

```
> round(eval.penalty(create.fourier.basis(c(0,1),5),vec2Lfd(c(0,(2*pi)^2,0), c(0,1))))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0       0       0
[2,]    0    0    0       0       0
[3,]    0    0    0       0       0
[4,]    0    0    0 2215044       0
[5,]    0    0    0       0 2215038
```

It is also easy to calculate this matrix analytically. We have that
$$
 L\phi_0(t)=0,
 \quad
 L\phi_{2r-1}(t)
 =\sqrt 2\cdot r\omega^3(1-r^2)\cos(r\omega t),
 \quad\text{and}\quad
 L\phi_{2r}(t)
 =-\sqrt 2\cdot r\omega^3(1-r^2)\sin(r\omega t).
$$
Hence, $L\phi_1(t)=0$ and $L\phi_2(t)=0$. Since $\int_0^1\sin(4\pi s)\cos(4\pi s)ds=0$, the only two non-zero entries of $\mathbf R$ are $\mathbf R_{44}$ and $\mathbf R_{55}$. We have that $\int_0^1\sin^2(4\pi s)ds=\int_0^1\cos^2(4\pi s)ds=1/2$, $(\sqrt 2\cdot 2(2\pi)^3(1-2^2))^2/2\approx2215041$ and hence
$$
 \mathbf R\approx
 \begin{bmatrix}
  0&0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&2215041&0\\
  0&0&0&0&2215041\\
 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
But this does not coincide with the output that I get using the `fda` package. We can see from the analytic computations that the non-zero values should be equal but they are not equal in `R`. So I suspect that the `fda` package does something additionally that I am not aware of.  Or am I making a mistake somewhere? Could someone shed some light on this discrepancy?

Any help is much appreciated!